# Assign proxies and user agents inside start_urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I am adding a second spider to my scrapy program and I am only scraping one URL in this spider so I was wondering if there was a way to just set my proxy and user agent inside start_urls or if not is there a way to set them inside this spider?

```
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'login_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.starcitygames.com/myaccount/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # login and scrape website
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'login_spider'
    my_urls = ['https://www.starcitygames.com/myaccount/']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url self.my_urls:
            yield Request(url, meta={'proxy': 'YOUR PROXY HERE'})

    def parse(self, response):
        # login and scrape website
```